# User action before continue a PHP code

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I am using the below php code to create and store a cookie.

```
 if ($logged_in_user['slots'] > $this->devices_model->count_devices($logged_in_user['id'])) {
//HERE SHOULD BE PLACED WHAT I NEED
        $cookie = array(
            'name' => 'kolass_app',
            'value' => md5(uniqid($logged_in_user['id'], true)),
            'device' => $this->agent->browser() . ' ' . $this->agent->version(),
            'expire' => time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60),
        );
        $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
        $data['user_id'] = $logged_in_user['id'];
        $data['device'] = $cookie['device'];
        $data['value'] = $cookie['value'];
        $this->devices_model->add_device($data);
        redirect(base_url());
    }
```

How can i get a user action yes or no before continuing the creation and saving of the cookie.

I am using Codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

You can't interact with the user from within a PHP script. What you need to do is first perform the first part (the `if`), and then show the user a page where they can select yes or no. If they select yes, send them to a page that performs the rest of your code. Beware though that you also need the `if` on that second page in case someone opens multiple tabs and then selects yes on all of them, getting more 'slots' than should actually be able to get.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<?php
if ($logged_in_user['slots'] > $this->devices_model->count_devices($logged_in_user['id'])) {

?>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var r = confirm("Are You sure??");
        if (r == true) {
            <?php
                $cookie = array(
                    'name' => 'kolass_app',
                    'value' => md5(uniqid($logged_in_user['id'], true)),
                    'device' => $this->agent->browser() . ' ' . $this->agent->version(),
                    'expire' => time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60),
                );

                $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
                $data['user_id'] = $logged_in_user['id'];
                $data['device'] = $cookie['device'];
                $data['value'] = $cookie['value'];
                $this->devices_model->add_device($data);
                redirect(base_url())
            ?>

        } else {
            alert('Not Served');
        }
    }
    </script>
<?php
}
else
{
    echo 'Not Loged In';
}
```